# Создать класс почтовый адрес организации

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

**Задание**:

> Построить описание класса, содержащего информацию о почтовом адресе организации. Предусмотреть возможность раздельного изменения составных частей
>   адреса, создания и уничтожения объектов этого класса. Написать программу, демонстрирующую работу с этим классом. Программа должна содержать меню, позволяющее осуществить проверку всех методов класса.

**Вопрос**:
Как сделать создание и удаление объектов класса? Как я понимаю условие, нужно сделать создание и удаление объектов по желанию пользователя.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;




class Mail
{
private:
    string zipcode;
    string city;
    string street;
    string room;
public:
    Mail(string zip_ = "00", string city_ = "City", string street_ = "Street", string room_ = "0");
    void ChangeZip(string & zip_);
    void ChangeCity(string & city_);
    void ChangeStreet(string & street_);
    void ChangeRoom(string & room_);
    void showmail() const;
    ~Mail() { };
};
Mail::Mail(string zip_, string city_, string street_, string room_)
{
    zipcode = zip_;
    city = city_;
    street = street_;
    room = room_;
}

void Mail::ChangeZip(string & zip_)
{
    zipcode = zip_;
}
void Mail::ChangeCity(string & city_)
{
    city = city_;
}
void Mail::ChangeStreet(string & street_)
{
    street = street_;
}
void Mail::ChangeRoom(string & room_)
{
    room = room_;
}
void Mail::showmail() const
{
    std::cout << zipcode << std::endl
        << city << std::endl
        << street << std::endl
        << room << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Если по желанию пользователя, используйте диначически распределнную память: `Mail* mail = new Mail();` и `delete mail;`

Comment: Спасибо. А  в моём случае он будет удалён только при выходе из области видимости?

Comment: В случае если объект имеет автоматическую продолжительность хранения (`Mail mail();`) - объект будет деструирован при выходе из области видимости.

Comment: @acade Только `Mail mail();` - это объявление функции. :Р

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да. Невнимателен. Анализ действительно неприятный. `Mail mail{}`.